# overriding class style with button:disabled pseudo-selector's style without important

Tags: css, css-specificity

I have a CSS stylesheet where I am styling a `button` element. What I am having trouble with is the `button:disabled` selector's style, which is going to be overridden by the additional classes applied to the element. Consider the following `.primary` class:

```css
button { background-color: #F5F5F5; border-color: #F0F0F0; color: #000; }
button:hover { background-color: #FFF; }
button:active { background-color: #E5E5E5; }
button:disabled { background-color: transaprent; border-color: transparent; color: #777; }

button.primary { background-color: #9F03FF; border-color: #8400DA; color: #FFF; }
button.primary:hover { background-color: #AF2CFF; }
button.primary:active { background-color: #7800C1; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button disabled="disabled">Default disabled</button>

<!--
  the following will appear with the button.primary style
  and will react to :hover and :active state changes
  instead of showing the button:disabled style
-->
<button class="primary" disabled="disabled">Primary disabled</button>
```

In the design I'm trying to implement, all disabled buttons will always have the same style, that of the default disabled button, no matter which color styling class is applied.
I know I could apply the style again on a `button.primary:disabled` selector, but that would duplicate that style a lot (there are 6 color styling classes, with both light and dark variants, totaling 12 duplications).
I know I could also use `!important` just for the `button:disabled` style, and I would be fine with this - but I am looking for ways to avoid it, if possible.
Finally, I could use the `:not(:disabled)` selector on all color styling classes, but it produces quite ugly and not easily readable code.

How can I achieve my styling without duplicating the `:disabled` style, and without using `!important`?

Comment: You have a typo on `transaprent => transparent` .  have you tried : `button:disabled,
button.primary:disabled {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #777;
}` & eventually `button.primary:disabled:hover`?

Comment: _"I know I could apply the style again on a button.primary:disabled selector, but that would duplicate that style a lot"_ - you don't need to "duplicate" the list of properties you assign, you can simply use multiple selectors in your rule. `button:disabled, button.primary:disabled, button.foobar:disabled { ... }`

Comment: @CBroe i did see it ;) , but the tag css-specifity is also there . no magic but specifity here . have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes against how CSS cascades. What I would do is create a class called

```
 .if-disabled:disabled {
...... your styling here
}
```

And then

```
<button class="primary if-disabled" />
```

I might tweak it for readability, and if you are using any kind of library, there are a lot of ways to do this efficiently, but the trick is to create a more specific styling that you can put anywhere.

Comment: Eventually, I have used a similar solution, but I have created a class `.disabled` with the appropriate style, without the `:disabled` pseudo-selector. Then I made sure that it was always the last class applied. The disabled attribute is still applied as well: `<button class="primary something other disabled" disabled="disabled">`

Comment: I have used this pattern myself. It's definitely important to not skip the attribute because that's important for screen readers.